# Issue with searching in Raven db

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, ravendb

I am using RavenDb for storing data. Document have columns like Id, Name, Description etc.

I set indexing as "Analyzed" for "Name" field which obviously searching entered text as "Contains" and in query I am using
        it as "StartsWith" This is working fine.
        See below Code:

```
    index setting
    //this.Indexes.Add(x => x.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);

    //Data retrieving Code
    //var resultSet = from temp in Query<Model>(Index.NAME)
    //.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(Searchterm))
    // select new { temp.Name }
```

My problem is let's say Name in database is "ABC PQR XYZ"
        CASE1(STARTS WITH): When I type "ABC" in search box, I am getting proper record as above.
        CASE2(WHOLE WORD SEARCH): When I type "ABC P" or "ABC PQ" or "ABC PQR", I am not getting any results. (THIS IS THE PROBLEM)
        CASE3(CONTAINS): when I type "PQR" or "XYZ", I am getting record   properly

Now when I change index to default like:

```
    //this.Indexes.Add(x => x.Name, FieldIndexing.Default);
```

From above CASE1 & 2 is working but case3 is not.

Is there any way I can get all 3 cases working? Any help will be really appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

When you use analyzed, what happens is that your text is broken into individual terms.

Analyzed means that the terms in the index are:

[ABC, PQR, XYZ]

For case 1, starts with, it is easy to see how it works.
For case 2, whole word, you don't *have* any term with ABC P, or something like that.

And for case 3, as well, there is no terms that contains that.

Comment: Yes, when i use Analyzed, terms breaks as [ABC, PQR, XYZ].

Comment: Yes, when i use Analyzed, terms breaks as [ABC, PQR, XYZ]. Please note that "ABC PQR XYZ" is single word as "Name" in db. So what i want is: CAES1: When i type "ABC" in search box it should return me whole name like "ABC PQR XYZ" CAES2: When i type "ABC P" or "ABC PQ" or "ABC PQR" in searchbox i should get "ABC PQR XYZ". CAES3: when i type "PQR" or "XYZ" then also i want whole word "ABC PQR XYZ" as a result.

Comment: Index the field multiple times, once with analyzed, once without. Then search on the relevant index field appropriately.

Comment: i tried but it is not working.. Can you please provide me an example?    Actually "ABC PQR XYZ" is a value of single field "Name"

Comment: Name = this.Name,
AnalyzedName = this.Name

And mark the AnalyzedName as analyzed.

Comment: This is not working.. I don't have field "AnalyzedName" in db.

Comment: Ask in the mailing list, with full details